# Find in Double Nested Array MongoDB based on index

Tags: mongodb, count, doctrine

i want to get count in nested array by index

i found one solution but that work if array key has name

```
db.mycollection.find({
    "someArray.someNestedArray.name": "value"
})
```

But my double nested array in based on index  like below

```
{
  "_id": "5dde88cd97e54f7c1a38da40",
  "list_id": [
    [
      2
    ]
  ]
}
```

I tried solution to get count like this

```
 $users = $this->dm->createQueryBuilder(ClientUser::class)
            ->field('list[0][0]')
            ->equals(2)
            ->getQuery()->count();

$users = $this->dm->createQueryBuilder(ClientUser::class)
            ->field('list.[0].[0]')
            ->equals(2)
            ->getQuery()->count();
```

and

```
  $users = $this->dm->createQueryBuilder(ClientUser::class)
        ->field('list.0.0')
        ->equals(2)
        ->getQuery()->count();
```

but that doesnot work .

Any idea how can i get count by nested index ? i want to apply it for 100k records so dont want to loop records in general foreach

Comment: Please use plain json for document examples, not images.

Comment: ok , done .....

Answer (score 1):

You still can use [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation):

```
 $users = $this->dm->createQueryBuilder(ClientUser::class)
        ->field('list.0.0')
        ->equals(2)
        ->getQuery()->count();
```

[Example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/r_WvK-2VtZ3)

Comment: ok , your point valid , how can a find the count ? actually i am using doctrine mongodb odm .in your example i tried for aggrgate and count..like db.orders.find().count().. . but it is not working

Comment: In which way it doesn't work?  `db.collection.count({"list_id.0.0": 2})` works fine.

Comment: i tried again at https://mongoplayground.net/p/pGP3CemtTXM ...it says ...invalid query: 
  must match db.coll.find(...) or db.coll.aggregate(...)

Comment: ah, it's a limitation of the playground. It works on real db.

Comment: ok , any guess how to similar things can work in doctrine mongo ?